# Code runs fine with breakpoints but NOT without them

Tags: c++, c, visual-studio, winapi, visual-c++

```
LRESULT CALLBACK ProcessMsgs(HWND hwnd, UINT msg, WPARAM param, LPARAM lparam) {
    switch (msg) {
    case WM_HOTKEY: {
        WORD AUXKEY = LOWORD(lparam);
        WORD MKEY = HIWORD(lparam);
        INPUT ip;
        ip.type = INPUT_KEYBOARD;
        ip.ki.time = 0;
        ip.ki.dwExtraInfo = 0;
        ip.ki.dwFlags = KEYEVENTF_UNICODE;
        ip.ki.wVk = 0; // 0 because of unicode
        if (AUXKEY == MOD_ALT) {
            switch (MKEY) { // Lowercase
            case 0x41: // A
                ip.ki.wScan = 0xE1; // lowercase a with accent
                break;
            case 0x4E: // N
                ip.ki.wScan = 0xF1; // lowercase n with tilde accent
                break;
            case 0x4F: // O
                ip.ki.wScan = 0xF3; // lowercase o with accent
                break;
            case 0x55: // U
                ip.ki.wScan = 0xFA; // lowercase u with accent
                break;
            case 0x49: // I
                ip.ki.wScan = 0xED; // lowercase i with accent
                break;
            case 0xBD: // DASH
                ip.ki.wScan = 0x2014; // em dash
                break;
            }
            SendInput(1, &ip, sizeof(INPUT)); // breakpoint here
        }
        if (AUXKEY == MOD_ALT + MOD_SHIFT) {
            switch (MKEY) { // Uppercase
            case 0x41: // A
                ip.ki.wScan = 0xC1; // uppercase a with accent
                break;
            case 0x4E: // N
                ip.ki.wScan = 0xF1; // uppercase n with tilde accent
                break;
            case 0x4F: // O
                ip.ki.wScan = 0xD2; // uppercase o with accent
                break;
            case 0x55: // U
                ip.ki.wScan = 0xDA; // uppercase u with accent
                break;
            case 0x49: // I
                ip.ki.wScan = 0xCD; // uppercase i with accent
                break;
            }
            SendInput(1, &ip, sizeof(INPUT));

        }
        ip.ki.dwFlags = KEYEVENTF_KEYUP + KEYEVENTF_UNICODE; // KEYEVENTF_KEYUP for key release
        SendInput(1, &ip, sizeof(INPUT));
        return 0;
    }
    case WM_DESTROY:
        PostQuitMessage(0);
        return 0;
    default:
        return DefWindowProc(hwnd, msg, param, lparam);
    }
}
```

This code types a vowel with an accent on it when combined with the ALT key. It recieves the message `WM_HOTKEY` from registered hotkeys like this:

```
    RegisterHotKey(
        TheWindow,
        NULL,
        MOD_ALT,
        0x41 // A
    );
```

There are hotkeys for all vowels, the letter N, and the dash character. The problem i'm having is the fact that the code works fine when I use a breakpoint on the line of the initial SendInput, but when I run it normally, no letter with accent is typed. All those breaks are there because the switch would always use the last case, I have no idea why.

The thing is when I run this very alpha and primitive version of the code I developed prior to the aforementioned code, it works fine without needing breakpoints (this version used CTRL as the indicator, I changed it to ALT because there are so many functions of programs that use CTRL plus a letter for user functions... the RegisterHotKey function uses `MOD_CONTROL` instead of `MOD_ALT` accordingly):

```
switch (msg) {
    case WM_HOTKEY:
        INPUT ip;
        ip.type = INPUT_KEYBOARD;
        ip.ki.wScan = 0xE1; // lowercase a with accent
        ip.ki.time = 0;
        ip.ki.dwExtraInfo = 0;
        ip.ki.dwFlags = KEYEVENTF_UNICODE;
        ip.ki.wVk = 0; // 0 because of unicode
        SendInput(1, &ip, sizeof(INPUT));

        ip.ki.dwFlags = KEYEVENTF_KEYUP | KEYEVENTF_UNICODE; // KEYEVENTF_KEYUP for key release
        SendInput(1, &ip, sizeof(INPUT));
        return 0;
    case WM_DESTROY:
        PostQuitMessage(0);
        return 0;
    default:
        return DefWindowProc(hwnd, msg, param, lparam);
    }
```

I know that I can use identifiers to simplify some of this, but regardless... that code functions, just with breakpoints... So odd.

Comment: You have a [Heisenbug](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heisenbug).

Comment: It's a Heisenbug but positive.

Comment: "breaks are there because the switch would always use the last case, I have no idea why." are you calling the `break` statement a "breakpoint" by any chance? can you confirm?

Comment: No, I noticed that in my preview before posting so I tried to explicate them. The breakpoint i'm referring to is visual studio's ability to halt execution at the beginning of a certain line and resume when the developer states to. The break i'm talking about is the actual c++ keyword (is it a keyword?).

Comment: @ohno `break` is a keyword & treated as a statement. cases in a switch statement [fallthrough by default](https://www.learncpp.com/cpp-tutorial/switch-fallthrough-and-scoping/), that's the way they work in c/c++. Since C++17 you should get a warning though that this happens (if you're compiling with warnings enabled), unless you mark it with the [`[[fallthrough]]` attribute](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/attributes/fallthrough).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

##### Problem

I unfortunately don't have a Windows System on hand to test, but i think i can guess what your problem is - but nice heisenbug, took me quite some time to figure out :D

Keep in mind that even if you have a registered hotkey the target window will still get the keypresses as well.
In addition to that `SendInput` [will not reset the keyboard state](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-sendinput#remarks):

> This function does not reset the keyboard's current state. Any keys that are already pressed when the function is called might interfere with the events that this function generates. To avoid this problem, check the keyboard's state with the GetAsyncKeyState function and correct as necessary.

So from the view of the target window you would see the following key events:

- `ALT` down
- `A` down
- (hotkey activates)
- `á` down
- `á` up
- (user needs some time to release the keys)
- `A` up
- `ALT` up

Whereas if you're debugging, you'll probably release the keys once you hit the breakpoint, so the sequence would look like this:

- `ALT` down
- `A` down
- (hotkey activates)
- (breakpoint hits)
- (user releases keys)
- `A` up
- `ALT` up
- (resume process)
- `á` down
- `á` up

So that's the most likely reason why it works when you're debugging - you're releasing the keys once the breakpoint is hit.

The ALT-Key is a bit evil in itself - mainly because as long as you're holding down the ALT-Key the window will **not** get `WM_KEYDOWN` messages but only `WM_SYSKEYDOWN` messages: [Key-Down and Key-Up Messages](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/learnwin32/keyboard-input#key-down-and-key-up-messages)

> The WM_SYSKEYDOWN message indicates a system key, which is a key stroke that invokes a system command. There are two types of system key:
>
> - ALT + any key
> - F10
>
> All other key strokes are considered nonsystem keys and produce the WM_KEYDOWN message. This includes the function keys other than F10.

So basically the target app will ignore your input entirely because it only receives it as a SYSKEY message.

---

##### Solution

You can fix this by checking if the ALT key (or any other of the modifier keys) is still down when your hotkey is called, e.g. via [`GetAsyncKeyState()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-getasynckeystate) and then call `SendInput()` with a release event for that modifier key, then send your special character, and then revert the state of the modifier key back.

Also i would recommend batching up all the sent key events into a single `SendInput()` to make sure no user-input (or other programmatic input) is interleaved between your input events.

e.g.:

```cpp
std::vector<INPUT> inputEvents;

short altKeyState = GetAsyncKeyState(VK_MENU);
// if we can't get the current input state
// we most likely aren't allowed to inject input
if(altKeyState == 0) return 0;
bool isAltDown = altKeyState < 0;
if(isAltDown) {
    INPUT ip;
    ip.type = INPUT_KEYBOARD;
    ip.ki.time = 0;
    ip.ki.dwExtraInfo = 0;
    ip.ki.dwFlags = KEYEVENTF_SCANCODE | KEYEVENTF_KEYUP;
    ip.ki.wVk = VK_MENU;
    inputEvents.push_back(ip);
}
// TODO: Add other modifier keys that might interfere with input

// Generate your char input
INPUT ips;
ips.type = INPUT_KEYBOARD;
ips.ki.wScan = 0xE1;
ips.ki.time = 0;
ips.ki.dwExtraInfo = 0;
ips.ki.dwFlags = KEYEVENTF_UNICODE;
ips.ki.wVk = 0;
inputEvents.push_back(ips);

if(isAltDown) {
    INPUT ip;
    ip.type = INPUT_KEYBOARD;
    ip.ki.time = 0;
    ip.ki.dwExtraInfo = 0;
    ip.ki.dwFlags = KEYEVENTF_SCANCODE;
    ip.ki.wVk = VK_MENU;
    inputEvents.push_back(ip);
}
// TODO: Add other modifier keys that might interfere with input


// Submit all inputs to the queue
UINT result = SendInput(inputEvents.size(), &inputEvents[0], sizeof(INPUT));
if(result == inputEvents.size()) {
    // SUCCESS! Injected all inputs
} else if (result > 0) {
   // Partial success, something failed, not really much you can do here other than call GetLastError()
} else {
  // blocked by other thread
}
```

Note that your program is still subject to UIPI (User Interface Privilege Isolation), so you can't use `SendInput()` to inject symbols into programs running with a higher integrity level.

If you have focus on a window of a program with a higher integrity level it won't get your `SendInput()` messages at all - but you also won't be able to detect the failure at all.
(Unless it used [`ChangeWindowMessageFilter(Ex)`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-changewindowmessagefilter) to allow keyboard input from lower-priority processes)

Comment: Thank you for this solution, I would've never figured this out myself. And to believe you write code that compiles for Windows without a Windows PC... you are truly talented in this labyrinth of a language.